# How do I load a JComboBox with values from an Array or ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox

I need to put the following array into a JComboBox and then store the selected value when the "Submit" button is clicked.

```
    listOfDepartments = new String[5];
    listOfDepartments[0] = "Mens Clothing";
    listOfDepartments[1] = "Womens Clothing";
    listOfDepartments[2] = "Childrens Clothing";
    listOfDepartments[3] = "Electronics";
    listOfDepartments[4] = "Toys";

    //Department: ComboBox that loads from array

    // Store values
    JButton buttonSubmit = new JButton();
    buttonSubmit.setText("Submit");
    container.add(buttonSubmit);

     buttonSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //store value from combobox in a variable
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, create a model...

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(listOfDepartments);
comboBox.setModel(model);
```

Second, get the selected value when the `actionPerformed` event is raised...

```
String value = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

Take a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details.

Comment: That code does not work. The getSelectedValue command isn't even a command of a JComboBox.

Comment: And did you make an effort to read the link or look up the java docs? Check update